# Selenium grid - test is not running in parallel instead it runs twice on each emulator

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, appium

I'm trying to run parallel test on appium using selenium grid. Weirdly it runs twice on each device.

Example I have 2 devices and 2 test cases, it runs the 2 test cases in each device. In total 4 test cases were ran.

I've been trying to wrap my head on what might've gone wrong but I'm not sure what's causing this.

DriverManager class:

```
package com.universalapp.utility;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class DriverManager {

    private static final ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver<MobileElement>> appiumDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private final CapabilityFactory capabilityFactory = new CapabilityFactory();

    public static synchronized AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getAppiumDriver() {
        return appiumDriver.get();
    }

    public static synchronized void setAppiumDriver(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        appiumDriver.set(driver);
    }


    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({"platformVersion", "udid"})
    public void setup(String platform, String udid) throws IOException {
        String[] platformInfo = platform.split(" ");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = this.capabilityFactory.getCapabilities(platform, udid);
        if (platformInfo[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ANDROID")) {
            setAppiumDriver(new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(UniversalAppConstants.COMMON_APP_DETAILS.HUB_URL), caps));
        } else {
            setAppiumDriver(new IOSDriver<>(new URL(UniversalAppConstants.COMMON_APP_DETAILS.HUB_URL), caps));
        }
        System.out.println("Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("Hashcode of web driver instance = " + getAppiumDriver().hashCode());
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void teardown() {
        getAppiumDriver().quit();
    }

}
```

Runner class:

```
package com.universalapp.runner;

import com.universalapp.utility.DriverManager;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.FeatureWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.PickleWrapper;
import io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/json/output.json", "html:target/html/", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"},
        features = "src/main/feature/",
        glue = "com.universalapp.stepDefinition",
        tags = "@Test",
        monochrome = true
)

public class RunnerTest extends DriverManager {

    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() {
        this.testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "feature")
    public void features(PickleWrapper eventWrapper, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        this.testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(eventWrapper.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] feature() {
        return this.testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        this.testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

}
```

TestNg xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="emulator-5554">
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="Android 8.0"/>
        <parameter name="udid" value="emulator-5554"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.universalapp.runner.RunnerTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="emulator-5556">
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="Android 10.0"/>
        <parameter name="udid" value="emulator-5556"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.universalapp.runner.RunnerTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Have you ever run Cucumber tests in parallel? I suspect what you're showing might not actually work. Refer to this [cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/#testng). Another thing is that you're mentioning Selenium grid in your question title. However I cannot see any references to grid in your code..

Comment: @AlexeyR. yes similar setup would work for web. But not for mobile unfortunately. using this as reference to parallel mobile automation with cucumber https://www.swtestacademy.com/appium-cucumber-parallel-test-execution/

Comment: @tiredqa_18, did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: hey @MoOoG unfortunately i didn't find a solution. A workaround  was implemented whereby I created 2 runnerTest files (each has its own respective test cases). So one simulator will have a specific runnerTest file

Comment: I did the same - so I have 2 CucumberRunners, both pointing to the same feature file. Note: I'm not using the TestNG.
However, I created 2 simulators with the same name and OS version (I'd expect that selenium grid will know which one to pick), but when I run both runners at the same time from gradle, the same device is picked for both executions. Any idea what could be the issue?
(In the console, I can see that both runners are running in parallel)

Comment: @MoOoG interesting. do you think it could be due to the emulator having the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your second emulator is active and displaying under `adb devices`. By default every first emulator will have `id : emulator-5554`

Comment: it is active. it's running on both of the devices. just twice

Comment: Try replacing @ BeforeMethod of TestNG with @ Before of Cucumber and check still its the same. Try to store the value of @ Parameters({"platformVersion", "udid"}) from @ BeforeMethod in some variables and invoke in your setup()